# Regular expression in apache configuration file

Tags: regex, apache, apache-config

I need to turn off php_flag for some directories on my server.

The directory name is 'images/' and is located in these directories:

/var/www/html/mysite1/images/

/var/www/html/anysitename/images/

/var/www/html/something/images/

....

What regular expression do i need to insert in apache config file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/var/www/html/(mysite1|something|[^/]+)/images/
```

Meaning: Either "mysite" or "something" or "a character sequence containing anything but a forward slash".

Answer (score 0):

Apache use Perl-compatible regular expression as mention [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html).

You can check your regular expressions with this online tool: https://regex101.com/r/gO4eS8/5

As mention in [Apache's documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/new_features_2_2.html), Apache understand v5 Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) from version 2.2.

For this case the following regular expression should do the job (matching directories and content): `/var/www/html/(|[^/]+)/images/?(?:[^\/]+)?$`

Test string:

```
/folder1/images/test1
/var/www/html/images
/folder2/images/test1
/folder2/mysite1/test2
/var/www/html/mysite2/images/foo.png
/var/www/html/anysitename/images/
/var/www/html/something/images/
```

Strings matching:

```
/var/www/html/mysite2/images/foo.png
/var/www/html/anysitename/images/
/var/www/html/something/images/
```